# View Controller как прототип, возможно ли это?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tableview, navigationcontroller

Моя цель - древовидно выводить данные

Сейчас, при клике по ячейки, мы переходим глубже в этом дереве и отображает это на следующем экране(весь список подчиненных этой ячейки)
Создаю одинаковые view controller для отображение этих таблиц и переключение между ними, в зависимости от глубины, но это ни есть корректно, ведь мы не можем знать заранее глубину дерева -> сколько таких экранов понадобится, можно ли их создавать программно с определенным интерфейсом? Либо может это все возможно реализовать в одном table view с такими переключениями, с возможностью вернутся назад?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос не ясень, необходимо при клике на ячейку переходить в новое вью с данными этой ячейки ??

Comment: @ВикторМишустин  да

Comment: В ситуации, где вы не знаете точно как будет происходить навигация, вам надо просто указать в storyboard что вы хотите иметь во view и все переходы между экранами делать программно. второй вариант в ответе @ВикторМишустин это иллюстрирует.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, ты без проблем можешь создавать одинаковые viewController (из кода, xib, storyboard) и передавать в них массивы для отображения.

Если не хочешь делать много контроллеров, добавь в первые контроллер одну секцию/ячейку (Назад или ".."). По клику на нее переходишь на уровень выше. По клику на ячейку с данными переходишь на уровень ниже.

Answer (score 1):

Для решения может быть несколько вариантов.

1. Использовать патерн программирования `Singlton`. Его назначение в том, чтобы сделать объект класса единственным экземпляром в системе.

Создаете класс с нужными вам property
для примера.

```
SingleTone.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SingleTone : NSObject  
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * titleString;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end


SingleTone.m
#import "SingleTone.h"

@implementation SingleTone

@synthesize titleString;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedManager{
    static SingleTone *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}


@end
```

Таким образом создаете класс `SingleTone`
После этого задаете параметры свойству которое прописали, в нужном вам месте.

Ванном случае в первом контролере методе делегата прописываем сеттер `stringArray` является массивом для заполнения заголовков в ячейках.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[[SingleTone sharedManager] setTitleString:[stringArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
}
```

Каждый раз когда вы будете нажимать на новую ячейку данные будут перезаписываться.

Что бы достать строку в новом контроллере нужно использовать следующий метод.

```
NSString * newString = [[SingleTone sharedManager] titleString];
```

И эту строку уже вставлять куда нужно;

2. Заранее записать в `property` контроллера к которому переходишь, данные.

В новом контроллере в хедере создаешь свойство

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * titleString
```

При переходе из первого контроллера перед тем как ты делаешь push, передавать данные.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ViewControllerSecondTable * detail = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerSecondTable"];
    detail.titleString = [stringArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
}
}
```

Останется только в новом контроллере вывести это свойство где тебе необходимо.

```
NSString * newString = self.titleString
```

Вообще вариантов передачи очень много, для каждого случая подходит свой.

Comment: вопрос состоит не в передаче данных, а в том, как избежать создания вручную с десяток одинаковых экранов, для переключения между ними

Comment: 'Singleton' это одно слово, не надо капитализировать T (и 'e' в конце нету)

Comment: Спасибо, поправил